# Need help with problem with anonymous ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs

```
i have:

var answers_json = [{
    name: "email",
    mapping: "answer.respondent.email"
}, {
    name: "group",
    mapping: "answer.respondent.respondent_group_id"
}, {
    name: "text",
    mapping: "answer.text"
}, {
    name: "scale",
    mapping: "answer.scale"
}, {
    name: "created_at",
    mapping: "answer.created_at",
    type: "date",
    dateFormat: "c"
}];


var answers_columns = [{
    id: "email",
    header: a_email,
    width: 240,
    sortable: true,
    resizable: false,
    menuDisabled: true,
    dataIndex: "email",
    //renderer: anonim_fun i need to write function?
}, {
    id: "group",
    header: "<div style=text-align:center>" + a_group + "</div>",
    width: 55,
    sortable: true,
    resizable: false,
    menuDisabled: true,
    dataIndex: "group"
}, {
    id: "text",
    header: a_answer,
    width: 550,
    sortable: true,
    resizable: false,
    menuDisabled: true,
    dataIndex: "text"
}, {
    id: "scale",
    header: a_scale,
    width: 50,
    sortable: true,
    resizable: false,
    menuDisabled: true,
    dataIndex: "scale"
}, {
    id: "created_at",
    header: a_added_date,
    width: 120,
    sortable: true,
    resizable: false,
    menuDisabled: true,
    dataIndex: "created_at",
    xtype: "datecolumn",
    format: "Y-m-d H:i:s"
}];
```

Problem is follow:

I have tables (as you can see) ..if respondent answered and he putted flag to (I ASK ANONYMOUS) then (IN MY VERSION) `respondent_id` gets 0 as id and in tale respondents there are user with some id called anonymous and then in `extjs` i see - anonymous (from respondent_id).

This works, but there are another way.. add field is_anonymous into inquiry table (relation between answers & respondents tables). but answers_json in column email get info about `answer.respondent.email`... How i can do another way with just adding field `is_annonymous` (and if yes = 1, if no = 0). this is much clever. But how it write in extJS? Function? AND HOW?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `convert:` as part of your field definition. Look at the current value and replace it with what you prefer.

```
{
    name: "email",
    mapping: "answer.respondent.email"
   convert: function(val) {
      if(val=="....") {
         return "(anonymous)"
   }
},
```

Comment: i dotn what replace email, i want to replace in my inquiry table (relation) when field is_anonymous = 1